# Drupal: Sorting nodes according to various fileds

Tags: drupal, sorting

I am planning to make a site where i have a large list of restaurants, shop and events details(probably as nodes in drupal).
 Is it possible to make a page where i can sort the restaurants/Shops with a field name Postcode or/and State?
 Is it possible to make a page where i can show the clients the events happening on a particular week? particular state?
 is it possible for me to provide my site visiter to choose from a drop down menu the "state_name" and see the restaurants in that state.

I would like to know whether all these are possible using drupal?
 If i get an answer from you experts, i don't need to start my site in drupal, but if its possible i can start.

Just a precuationary question to avoid droping a project at mid way.

Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Much/all of what you describe above is doable via the Views module. Specifically, Views Exposed Filters, which allow the user to filter the results of a view by fields like Date or State. Here's a good tutorial to get you started:

- http://www.acquia.com/blog/s-files-adding-basic-search-fields-and-filters-views

The postal code search might be a bit trickier depending on if you want users to be able to search by proximity, for restaurants "In your area." In that case, you will likely need a more complex search capability. But I guess that will be true for other comparable CMSs such as WordPress, etc.

EDIT: Actually, it looks like this is doable via a Views module like http://drupal.org/project/geolocation_proximity.

At any rate, Views is likely a good candidate to meet your requirements.